# Nesting Grid with Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

So, I am having issues with getting material-ui grid to work as i want. I am trying to render a row with two columns.

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultLayout from '../layouts/default';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

class profile extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container spacing={8}>
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', height: '250px'}}></Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', height: '250px'}}></Grid>

      {/* Form two columns with next row*/}

      <Grid container={'true'} item sx={12}>
        <Grid item={'true'} xs={6} md={8} style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: '50px'}}></Grid>
        <Grid item={'true'} xs={6} md={4} style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', height: '50px'}}></Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid> 
  </React.Fragment>
)}}

module.exports = profile;
```

Currently, It is rendering:

[image]

I want the orange and green rows to be two columns on the same row. Side by side.

Can anyone decipher what is wrong with my code?

@material-ui/core: ^3.9.2

react: ^16.7.0

Answer (score 6):

I think the issue is that your first two 'rows' are marked with xs={12} and will take up the full page width. I'm also transitioning out of bootstrap (man...who knew react-bootstrap would be so buggy right!) and it's a bit of an adjustment...but in case you didn't figure it out, try this on?

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultLayout from '../layouts/default';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

class profile extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container spacing={8}>
      //the below columns will be full width! I've changed the 12 to 6
      <Grid item xs={6} style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', height: '250px'}}></Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6} style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', height: '250px'}}></Grid>

      {/* Form two columns with next row*/}

      <Grid container={'true'} item sx={12}>
        <Grid item={'true'} xs={6} md={8} style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: '50px'}}></Grid>
        <Grid item={'true'} xs={6} md={4} style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', height: '50px'}}></Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid> 
  </React.Fragment>
)}}

module.exports = profile
```

I haven't tested it out but should work?

Comment: fwiw, anytime you have a prop that is set to true, you can exclude the value. Instead of `<Grid item={'true'}>`, just use `<Grid item>`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [GridList](https://material-ui.com/api/grid-list/) and [GridListTitle](https://material-ui.com/api/grid-list-tile/).

Please try with below code to get desired output

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultLayout from '../layouts/default';
import GridList from "@material-ui/core/GridList";
import GridListTile from "@material-ui/core/GridListTile";

class profile extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GridList cols={1}>
          <GridListTile style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: '50px'}}>

          </GridListTile>
          <GridListTile style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', height: '50px'}}>

          </GridListTile>
      </GridList>
      <GridList cols={2}>
          <GridListTile style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: '50px'}}>

          </GridListTile>
          <GridListTile style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', height: '50px'}}>

          </GridListTile>
      </GridList>

  </React.Fragment>
)}}

module.exports = profile;
```

Comment: Can you show us how to make the column custom width?currently it makes equal width columns